# HTML CSS Positioning

Tags: html, css

So I am just fiddling for some curiosity on jsFiddle.
When I apply style on below HTML:

```
<p>Hello World</p>
```

Styles:

```
p {
  position:relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

The Hello World comes to the center horizontally but not vertically.

But , when I change the position from `relative` to `absolute`, 
the element aligns horizontally and vertically as well.

As I understand positioning, `top: 50%` should change the top of a block element.

Anything I am missing here (conceptually or otherwise)?

```css
p {
  position:relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;

}
```

```html
<p>Hello World</p>
```

Comment: Relative positioning works relative to parrent, but absolute works comparing to closest parent with position relative / absoute / fixed or if there is not, it possitions according to window height.

Comment: @Andris *Relative positioning works relative to parrent* --> it works relatively to the element position, not the parent

Comment: Well yes, but same time positioning is compared against parent. 'p' won't be 50% from top if parent height isn't 100% from window height in this example. This case 'relative' to work body should have css: {height: 100vh}

Comment: Answered!.......

Comment: @Andris , as far as I know relative is "relative to its original position in the flow" , didn't know about this parent stuff . Is there a link where I can study it properly ?
Thanks .

Comment: I don't know actually. I learned this while working on projects. But this is all, what is needed in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For position `relative`, it parent should have an static height. As I assign height to body it worked!.

```css
p{
  position:relative ;
  top : 50%;
  left : 50%;
}
body{
  height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello World</p>
```

Comment: now thats solid !
This height issue is not in absolute position ?

Comment: in absolute position it looks if one of parents has relative / absolute / fixed positions. If not, than it looks on windows height and positions accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

I have this kind of problem lot of time and to use position absolute some times are not a good idea so I have always used flex css.

```
body{
display: flex;
height: 100vh;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}
```

for p no css is required.

Comment: yeah @Deep , I know the flex box method , but I am trying to solidify my understanding of core concepts.
thanks for your answer thyough